# Assignment Rule firing for bulk records

Tags: apex, assignment-rules

Salesforce says to invoke a assignment Rule by marking " Assign using active assignment rule checkbox " to be checked.  This works fine for single records.

I am curious to know how does it work for bulk records? How will I be able to mark assignment check box to true for bulk records and ensure we are doing it in a right way,without impacting performance

a. Also, i am unable to figure out the corresponding field for this checkbox to use it in workflow or in Code?

Also, one work around that i have checked for single records is of :  setting this field at the pagelayout level. But not sure if this is sufficient to make it work for bulk records??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by 'bulk records'

If using DataLoader, you have to go to Settings and put the ID of the assignment rule, then Save

[image]

If using Apex DML, you need to use the `Database.insert` or `Database.update` methods, setting optional parameter `dmlOptions` as in this example:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= someAssignmentRuleId;

List<Lead> lInsList = new List<Lead> { 
                                       new Lead(company='ABC', lastname='Smith'),
                                       new Lead(company='DEF', lastname='Hills')
                                     };
Database.insert(lInsList,dmo);
```

In addition to using a specific assignment rule, you can have the default rules executed by using a different DMLOption:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;
```

Here, `useDefaultRule` means to use the default assignment ruleset as marked in the user interface.

If using the REST or SOAP API, there is an equivalent way to set DML Options that specify the assignment rule to use. These can be found in the documentation for those API services

Comment: thanks for the clarity. About default rule, what does this statement do and if we have 4 ruleentries then which would be defaulted: by  dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule= true;

Comment: i updated my answer - if you have 4 rule entries for one set of assignment rules, there is no default rule -- just rules executed in the specified order with the last rule being the otherwise case (if properly designed), and if not, then Leads get assigned to the default owner per Lead Settings

Comment: Ok got it, but also considering a different approach : can we directly populate the ownership field from the file used for importing data into salesforce? without actually depending on the assignment rule? In realtime,does it cause an issue.

Comment: ah -- the answer is definitely YES - you just need to include the proper ID value in the `ownerId` column

Comment: To clarify: you can have many rules with many rule entries. However, only one rule may be active at a time. This is known as the default rule. However, non-default rules can be called by ID through the API, but not the GUI.

Comment: @sfdcfox : One observation I saw recently, that the data import Wizard doesnt entertain the DMLOptions AssignmentRuleHeader options but the Apex Data loader or dataloer.io does entertain.. Have you seen this pattern ?

Comment: @JatinJain The old (and new) import wizards do allow you to specify a rule to import with, but do not allow "use default rule".